# Recycling an inflated view on Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a complicated ViewGroup for a fragment which is created every now and then.
Only 1 instance fragment can be shown at a time.

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow store the inflated view and just reuse it when the fragment is created again.

Obviously the view properties will have to be changed, but at least the view will not need to be inflated again.

I tried simply to store the view element as a static element and then check if it exists, and if does, use it.

However, I believe the View element has some fragment specific properties and if you use it with a fragment which has a different reference id, it will fail - well..it failed.

Has anyone tried to cache inflated views and reuse them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems very risky to reuse views across different fragments (although it's safe to reuse them in the same fragment).

What if the context changes, for example if your activity gets recreated? I guess you have to hope that no views call `getContext()` and try to use the activity context because it will be invalid and may lead to unexpected results.

What you can do is to be sure that you optimized your layout (like avoiding nested weights and `RelativeLayouts` when possible) or use custom views to simplify your layout.

Comment: Is it possible to re-use a fragment then? When I call popBack it pops into a cache and then when I call it, it uses the fragment from the cache? That would contain pre-inflated view as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. Even if you use `setRetainInstance(true)` it will still need to recreate the layout. The views are bound to the activity context and you can't do anything about it, if the activity gets recreated, you need to inflate the views again. That's the price of the multitasking offered by Android. Custom views are much, much faster than built-in views, did you try them?